How can I include specific cookies in a media request with media3 Exoplayer?
What I'm trying to do now is to make media requests with specific cookies. Here's the current situation: Since background playback must be possible, I referred to the documentation and retrieved the MediaController as follows. (Here, PlaybackService is an object that inherits from MediaSessionService.)
SessionToken sessionToken =
            new SessionToken(this.themedReactContext, new ComponentName(this.themedReactContext, PlaybackService.class));
ListenableFuture<MediaController> controllerFuture =
            new MediaController.Builder(this.themedReactContext, sessionToken).buildAsync();

controllerFuture.addListener(() -> {
      try {
        player = controllerFuture.get();
      } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
      }

      MediaItem mediaItem = ALibrary.getMediaItem();

      player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
      player.prepare();

      // ... play with the 'player'
});

Now, to embed cookies in the media request, I created a mediaSource using OkHttp as shown below.
private final OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

// CookieUtil is what I made
List<Cookie> cookies = CookieUtil.convertListToCookies(listOfCookieMap);
OkHttpClient client = httpClient
                .newBuilder()
                .cookieJar(new CookieJar() {
                  @Override
                  public void saveFromResponse(@NonNull HttpUrl httpUrl, @NonNull List<Cookie> list) {
                    //
                  }

                  @NonNull
                  @Override
                  public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(@NonNull HttpUrl httpUrl) {
                    return cookies;
                  }
                })
                .build();

OkHttpDataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new OkHttpDataSource.Factory(client);

MediaItem mediaItem = ALibrary.getMediaItem(); // The code shown above

MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem);

Now, I need to use the mediaSource, but the MediaController can only use mediaItem with setMediaItem and cannot use mediaSource (there is no setMediaSource). I've looked for various solutions but couldn't resolve this issue.
How can I include specific cookies in a media request?
(Note that I have to obtain mediaItem through an external library.)
